# How to create jQuery code for implement multiple slidetoggle in same page?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="panel">
    <a href="#" class="panel-tab">Previous year papers of Bank Clerks<span>&#9660;</span></a>
    <div class="panel-stage" id="panel-stage-1">
        <a href="#">SBI Clerk 2008</a><br />
        <a href="#">Ibps Clerk 2015</a><br />
    </div> 

    <a href="#" class="panel-tab">Previous Year Papers Of BHU CHS<span>&#9660;</span></a>

    <div class="panel-stage" id="panel-stage-2">
        <a href="#">CHS (Maths) -2013</a><br />
        <a href="#">CHS (Maths) -2014</a><br />
        <a href="#">CHS (Maths) -2015</a><br />
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="panel-tab">Previous Year Papers Of Lucknow University<span>&#9660;</span></a>

    <div class="panel-stage" id="panel-stage-3">
        <a href="#">B.Sc 3rd year -2013</a><br />
        <a href="#">CHS (Maths) -2016</a><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('.panel-tab').on('click', function (event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();

    $('.panel-stage').slideUp('fast');

    $(this).next('.panel-stage').slideToggle('slow', function (e) 
         {
         }); 
});
```

This code working means when I click on panel-stage-1 it slides down and when after this click on panel-stage-2 panel-stage-1 slides up and panel-stage-2 slides down but when I click on panel-stage taht is already slidedown, doesn't slideup.

Please correct me if I am missing something in code.

Comment: it gives the same result as my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you need to add `$('.panel-tab')` click event into `$(document).ready()`. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.panel-tab').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.panel-stage').slideUp('fast');
        $(this).next('.panel-stage').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

and add `.panel-stage {display:none}` into your style sheet to make sure it's always hidden before you click on `.panel-tab`

Comment: Doesn't work as i want it givess the same result as code i wrote

Answer (score 0):

You have to exclude the candidate `.panel-stage` from `slideUp` and apply only `slideToggle`

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/117269/)

Comment: You're  welcome. Can you vote up, if you found my answer helpful? Thanks